# Interpreting interaction effect with orthogonal polynomial contrast codes

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding, ancova, contrasts

I'm running a logistic regression with two categorical variables (sample_number: 1, 2, 3, 4; and sample_length: 60, 70, 80, 90, 100) and a continuous predictor (dot_size). My model in R looks like this:

```
logit = glm(formula = Response ~ sample_numerosity*sample_length*dot_sizes_mean_c,data = det_data_confounded)
```

I've ordered my factors and use the `contr.poly` function to create contrast coding for them. I've also checked my omnibus tests with

```
car::Anova(logit,type=3,family = binomial(link="logit"),icontrasts = c('poly.sum',"contr.poly"))
```

I mean centered the continuous predictor.

My question is in interpreting my interaction effect. The car package anova gives me this output:

```
                                                   LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
sample_numerosity                                   4.884  3  0.1804952    
sample_length                                      23.544  4  9.859e-05 ***
dot_sizes_mean_c                                   22.998  1  1.622e-06 ***
sample_numerosity:sample_length                    34.825 12  0.0004993 ***
sample_numerosity:dot_sizes_mean_c                  5.086  3  0.1656402    
sample_length:dot_sizes_mean_c                      6.527  4  0.1630820    
sample_numerosity:sample_length:dot_sizes_mean_c   35.785 12  0.0003508 ***
```

Which seems to make sense, we have an interaction between sample_numerosity and sample_length, which is the interaction I'm interested in. I'm confused about how to interpret this interaction in light of the fact I used polynomial contrast codes. If I look at the output from the glm function, where it breaks down the interactions for each pair of contrasts, I get this:

```
                                                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                           7.877e-01  2.151e-02  36.622  < 2e-16 ***
sample_numerosity.L                                  -1.208e-02  5.429e-02  -0.223 0.823897    
sample_numerosity.Q                                  -6.925e-02  4.302e-02  -1.610 0.107584    
sample_numerosity.C                                   6.637e-03  2.746e-02   0.242 0.809048    
sample_length.L                                       1.160e-01  4.656e-02   2.491 0.012788 *  
sample_length.Q                                       6.026e-02  4.519e-02   1.334 0.182487    
sample_length.C                                      -2.291e-01  5.246e-02  -4.367 1.31e-05 ***
sample_length^4                                       1.415e-02  4.787e-02   0.296 0.767599    
dot_sizes_mean_c                                      3.794e-04  7.911e-05   4.796 1.72e-06 ***
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.L                   4.691e-02  1.188e-01   0.395 0.693021    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.L                   9.560e-02  9.311e-02   1.027 0.304637    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.L                  -5.097e-02  5.675e-02  -0.898 0.369155    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.Q                   3.828e-01  1.134e-01   3.377 0.000744 ***
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.Q                  -1.339e-01  9.037e-02  -1.482 0.138439    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.Q                   1.833e-01  5.902e-02   3.106 0.001918 ** 
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.C                   6.557e-04  1.337e-01   0.005 0.996087    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.C                  -2.094e-01  1.049e-01  -1.996 0.046042 *  
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.C                  -2.811e-02  6.433e-02  -0.437 0.662108    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length^4                  -5.092e-02  1.187e-01  -0.429 0.668001    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length^4                  -1.492e-01  9.574e-02  -1.558 0.119360    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length^4                   1.858e-02  6.514e-02   0.285 0.775495    
sample_numerosity.L:dot_sizes_mean_c                 -1.405e-04  1.705e-04  -0.824 0.409858    
sample_numerosity.Q:dot_sizes_mean_c                 -1.932e-04  1.582e-04  -1.221 0.222120    
sample_numerosity.C:dot_sizes_mean_c                  2.057e-04  1.449e-04   1.419 0.156002    
sample_length.L:dot_sizes_mean_c                      4.487e-05  1.705e-04   0.263 0.792463    
sample_length.Q:dot_sizes_mean_c                     -4.315e-04  1.727e-04  -2.499 0.012518 *  
sample_length.C:dot_sizes_mean_c                      2.208e-06  1.826e-04   0.012 0.990352    
sample_length^4:dot_sizes_mean_c                      8.148e-05  1.815e-04   0.449 0.653609    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.L:dot_sizes_mean_c -5.912e-04  3.818e-04  -1.548 0.121655    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.L:dot_sizes_mean_c -2.049e-04  3.411e-04  -0.601 0.548055    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.L:dot_sizes_mean_c  3.216e-04  2.947e-04   1.091 0.275238    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.Q:dot_sizes_mean_c  8.641e-04  3.609e-04   2.394 0.016725 *  
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.Q:dot_sizes_mean_c -1.167e-03  3.454e-04  -3.379 0.000740 ***
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.Q:dot_sizes_mean_c -2.063e-04  3.291e-04  -0.627 0.530844    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length.C:dot_sizes_mean_c  5.385e-04  4.145e-04   1.299 0.194048    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length.C:dot_sizes_mean_c  2.617e-04  3.651e-04   0.717 0.473635    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length.C:dot_sizes_mean_c  4.139e-04  3.078e-04   1.344 0.178913    
sample_numerosity.L:sample_length^4:dot_sizes_mean_c  3.217e-04  3.653e-04   0.881 0.378589    
sample_numerosity.Q:sample_length^4:dot_sizes_mean_c -4.543e-04  3.631e-04  -1.251 0.210939    
sample_numerosity.C:sample_length^4:dot_sizes_mean_c  9.097e-04  3.609e-04   2.521 0.011773 *
```

It looks as if the interaction between numerosity and length is driven by an interaction between the linear trend in sample numerosity and the quadratic trend in sample length. What does this mean? I can't wrap my head around what it means for two trends to be interacting.

Any intuitive or rigorous explanation would be very helpful.

EDIT:

Here are the contrast codes I'm using for sample_numerosity

```
           .L   .Q         .C
[1,] -0.6708204  0.5 -0.2236068
[2,] -0.2236068 -0.5  0.6708204
[3,]  0.2236068 -0.5 -0.6708204
[4,]  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
```

and for sample_length

```
[1,] -0.6324555  0.5345225 -3.162278e-01  0.1195229
[2,] -0.3162278 -0.2672612  6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
[3,]  0.0000000 -0.5345225 -4.095972e-16  0.7171372
[4,]  0.3162278 -0.2672612 -6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
[5,]  0.6324555  0.5345225  3.162278e-01  0.1195229
```

I assume the interaction contrasts will just be multiplication of the relevant columns in the above matrices.

Comment: Can you request to output the complete (main effects + interactions) contrast coefficient matrix (L matrix)?

Comment: @ttnphns please see my edit to original post!

Comment: Is you factor design complete (no empty cells)? It would be nice if you show your data or a part of it. You could present a small artifical dataset if you dataset is big.

Comment: the factor design is complete with equal cell sizes (4 x 5 design)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, rather a comment.
Below is the complete contrast coefficient matrix as I can estimate it. Rows are contrasts (correspond to contrast variables - after the encoding of factors into contrast variables). Columns are all the cells of the design - marginal and cross.

The design was complete two-factor (Factor A, 4 levels X Factor B, 5 levels). The encoding type was Polynomial. The original levels of factor B were 60, 70, 80, 90, 100; however, since these appear to be equally spaced intervals, it is the same situation as levels 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
  contrast   a=1       a=2       a=3       a=4       b=1       b=2       b=3       b=4       b=5     a=1 b=1   a=1 b=2   a=1 b=3   a=1 b=4   a=1 b=5   a=2 b=1   a=2 b=2   a=2 b=3   a=2 b=4   a=2 b=5   a=3 b=1   a=3 b=2   a=3 b=3   a=3 b=4   a=3 b=5   a=4 b=1   a=4 b=2   a=4 b=3   a=4 b=4   a=4 b=5
(Factor A main effects contrasts)
1     a1  -.670820  -.223607   .223607   .670820   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721   .044721   .044721   .044721   .044721   .044721   .134164   .134164   .134164   .134164   .134164
2     a2   .500000  -.500000  -.500000   .500000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .100000   .100000   .100000   .100000   .100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000  -.100000   .100000   .100000   .100000   .100000   .100000
3     a3  -.223607   .670820  -.670820   .223607   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721  -.044721   .134164   .134164   .134164   .134164   .134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164  -.134164   .044721   .044721   .044721   .044721   .044721
(Factor B main effects contrasts)
4     b1   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.632456  -.316228   .000000   .316228   .632456  -.158114  -.079057   .000000   .079057   .158114  -.158114  -.079057   .000000   .079057   .158114  -.158114  -.079057   .000000   .079057   .158114  -.158114  -.079057   .000000   .079057   .158114
5     b2   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .534522  -.267261  -.534522  -.267261   .534522   .133631  -.066815  -.133631  -.066815   .133631   .133631  -.066815  -.133631  -.066815   .133631   .133631  -.066815  -.133631  -.066815   .133631   .133631  -.066815  -.133631  -.066815   .133631
6     b3   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.316228   .632456   .000000  -.632456   .316228  -.079057   .158114   .000000  -.158114   .079057  -.079057   .158114   .000000  -.158114   .079057  -.079057   .158114   .000000  -.158114   .079057  -.079057   .158114   .000000  -.158114   .079057
7     b4   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .119523  -.478091   .717137  -.478091   .119523   .029881  -.119523   .179284  -.119523   .029881   .029881  -.119523   .179284  -.119523   .029881   .029881  -.119523   .179284  -.119523   .029881   .029881  -.119523   .179284  -.119523   .029881
(Interaction contrasts)
8   a1b1   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .424264   .212132   .000000  -.212132  -.424264   .141421   .070711   .000000  -.070711  -.141421  -.141421  -.070711   .000000   .070711   .141421  -.424264  -.212132   .000000   .212132   .424264
9   a1b2   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.358569   .179284   .358569   .179284  -.358569  -.119523   .059761   .119523   .059761  -.119523   .119523  -.059761  -.119523  -.059761   .119523   .358569  -.179284  -.358569  -.179284   .358569
10  a1b3   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .212132  -.424264   .000000   .424264  -.212132   .070711  -.141421   .000000   .141421  -.070711  -.070711   .141421   .000000  -.141421   .070711  -.212132   .424264   .000000  -.424264   .212132
11  a1b4   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.080178   .320713  -.481070   .320713  -.080178  -.026726   .106904  -.160357   .106904  -.026726   .026726  -.106904   .160357  -.106904   .026726   .080178  -.320713   .481070  -.320713   .080178
12  a2b1   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.316228  -.158114   .000000   .158114   .316228   .316228   .158114   .000000  -.158114  -.316228   .316228   .158114   .000000  -.158114  -.316228  -.316228  -.158114   .000000   .158114   .316228
13  a2b2   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .267261  -.133631  -.267261  -.133631   .267261  -.267261   .133631   .267261   .133631  -.267261  -.267261   .133631   .267261   .133631  -.267261   .267261  -.133631  -.267261  -.133631   .267261
14  a2b3   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.158114   .316228   .000000  -.316228   .158114   .158114  -.316228   .000000   .316228  -.158114   .158114  -.316228   .000000   .316228  -.158114  -.158114   .316228   .000000  -.316228   .158114
15  a2b4   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .059761  -.239046   .358569  -.239046   .059761  -.059761   .239046  -.358569   .239046  -.059761  -.059761   .239046  -.358569   .239046  -.059761   .059761  -.239046   .358569  -.239046   .059761
16  a3b1   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .141421   .070711   .000000  -.070711  -.141421  -.424264  -.212132   .000000   .212132   .424264   .424264   .212132   .000000  -.212132  -.424264  -.141421  -.070711   .000000   .070711   .141421
17  a3b2   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.119523   .059761   .119523   .059761  -.119523   .358569  -.179284  -.358569  -.179284   .358569  -.358569   .179284   .358569   .179284  -.358569   .119523  -.059761  -.119523  -.059761   .119523
18  a3b3   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .070711  -.141421   .000000   .141421  -.070711  -.212132   .424264   .000000  -.424264   .212132   .212132  -.424264   .000000   .424264  -.212132  -.070711   .141421   .000000  -.141421   .070711
19  a3b4   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000   .000000  -.026726   .106904  -.160357   .106904  -.026726   .080178  -.320713   .481070  -.320713   .080178  -.080178   .320713  -.481070   .320713  -.080178   .026726  -.106904   .160357  -.106904   .026726
```

In a polynomial contrast type, contrasts correspond to the exponential components. With factor A of 4 levels, for example, contrast (contrast variable) a1 will tell linear effect on a response, a2 will tell quadratic effect that is "above" (incremental to) linear, a3 will tell cubic effect that is "above" linear and quadratic, and so on. An interaction contrast variable is, as always, the cross-multiplication. For example, contrast variable corresponding to contrast a1b1 is the a1 contrast variable * the b1 contrast variable.

Polynomial contrasts are orthogonal: if the design is balanced (equal frequencies in cells), all the contrast variables are uncorrelatated, i.e., main effects don't overlap and don't overlap with the interaction effect.